# header(Location:"") is not redirecting the page after image upload

Tags: php, image

In my site pages, I have a file named `view_all_choices`. Just see the choice images using the

The below variables are used to display the choice images. But after upload the images the redirection to the same page with their id is not working.

Here is the code for own page redirection:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  

$pollids = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pollid']);

$choiceid= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chid']);  

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$dir . $img);  

header("Location:view_all_choices.php?pollid=$pollids&chid=$choiceid");}
```

In my server it works fine. After image upload the page again redirected to above URL and the URL shows like this

```
http://domain.com/mysite/view_all_choices.php?pollid=3&chid=13
```

But after I moved the files to client server, after image upload the page again redirected to

```
http://domain.com/mysite/view_all_choices.php
```

So, the page shows empty image since there is no get id.

Comment: so `header("Location:view_all_choices.php?pollid=$pollid&chid=$chid");`

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); and check

Comment: after I get that variable, there is a if condition for image upload within that if condition I used the variables $pollids and $choiceid. So no problem with this variables. Please see the above changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue i can see is a **space** is missing after **location:** in header function.
so replace

```
header("Location:view_all_choices.php?pollid=$pollids&chid=$choiceid");
```

with

```
header("Location: view_all_choices.php?pollid=$pollids&chid=$choiceid");
exit();
```

If it still does not work make sure 
1 - there is no error in file upload
2 - all the variables has values for $pollids, $choiceid etc
3 - and there is no other redirect.

if you still see

```
http://domain.com/mysite/view_all_choices.php
```

This means its not redirected by

```
header("Location: view_all_choices.php?pollid=$pollids&chid=$choiceid");
exit(); // its a good practise to put exit after header redirect
```

Because if it is redirected by above code then you should see variables in query string

```
http://domain.com/mysite/view_all_choices.php?pollid=[value or empty]&chid=[value or empty]
```

If you are still unable to find out, try changing php file name, this will surely tell you who is redirecting the page.

```
header("Location: some_test_page.php?pollid=$pollids&chid=$choiceid");
```

Comment: also put exit after your header redirect